# Leak memory when open and closing revit documents

Tags: c#, memory, revit-api

I can't remember if this issue was discussed of if there is any issue at all.

I'm developing a plugin for Revit using Revit API and c#. During a work I open and close a lot of documents in background. After some time I face with slowing of a plugin process. I found that then i open document and close it, the Process Memory graphic in my Visual Studio didn't return to it's original value.

Example: before opening document the Process Memory is 700MB, after opening and loading the document it 3.3 GB (project is heavy), after closing the document the Memory didnt return to 700MB. It releases some and stays at 1.9GB. No documents opened in background.

I've tried use "using" when declaring Document, tried `app.PurgeReleasedAPIObjects()` method, tried even `System.GC.Collect()`, but it did not help. Process Memory remained 1.9GB

Comment: The Revit journal file is a log file that records every API call made by Revit. You can use it to track memory usage.

Comment: Have you checked out the video Autodesk put out on YouTube about troubleshooting this very issue? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tz5nvM1DtNc